# Why is it sometimes hard to engage reverse gear in a manual transmission?

Tags: manual-transmission, peugeot-207

When shifting from any gear other than 1st (while standing still, obviously), sometimes the reverse gear doesn't fully engage and the shifter will pop back to neutral. So I have to shift to 1st gear first and then to reverse for it to fully engage.

When shifting from 1st gear to reverse, sometimes the reverse gear doesn't fully engage and I have to shift to 2nd first before shifting to reverse.

I have observed this behaviour in multiple manual transmission cars, but it's most notable in my work's Peugeot 207.

I understand the basic workings of a manual transmission, how gears are selected by attaching the gear to the output shaft using a sleeve and how each gear (except reverse) uses a synchronizer ring to synchronize the gear speed with the speed of the output shaft, but I don't understand how the general design of a manual gearbox leads to this behavior. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Sounds like an operator error, ie not engaging reverse fully if it happens on many cars... Having driven **many** cars I have found the odd time it was my fault.

Comment: be glad it is like it is,if it had been syncronized you could shift from 4th to R just as easy as it is to shift from 2nd to 3rd.

Comment: @trondhansen Why wouldn't you want that to be possible? You should only shift to reverse when stationary, no matter from which gear you shift

Comment: you will not like to shift into R when driving at 100km/h sparks will fly.

Comment: Same goes when shifting to reverse when driving 30 km/h in 1st. Also there are situations where you would shift from 4th to reverse. For example when you're driving and want to turn around, so you press the clutch, brake and after you stopped, you switch from 4th to reverse in order to reverse in a side street so you can go the other way.

Comment: I've run into that problem on various vehicles back in the 60's and 70's with a parked vehicle, and the quick and easy procedure was to stop fighting the gear shift, move it to neutral, let the clutch all the way out, push the clutch back in, then shifting into reverse was easy.

Comment: For broadly two reasons: the car is going too fast or either clutch or gears are out of adjustment

Comment: Have you tried double clutching it? i.e release clutch in neutral position before reclutching and attempting an engage of the reverse? If you still experience trouble, that would be a clue.

Comment: @StianYttervik I haven't, but I'm sure it will work. I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the car and this behaviour is normal, because I've seen this happen on many (of not all) manual transmission cars I've driven. I was just wondering how this is related to the design of a manual gearbox. But thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: I've experienced this a lot in Fords (a ~2001 Focus and a 2013 Fiesta), but funnily not in a 2017 Focus. In the older cars, reverse was in the "6th gear" position and you can feel the gears not quite engaging. The 2017's reverse is next to 1st (and requires a collar to be pulled up on the stick to get it in there), and I've never experienced it in that car. In the older cars, sometimes a bit of extra force pushes it in, but often it requires what my wife refers to as a "double de-clutch" which may or may not be the right term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_clutch_(technique).

Comment: I would like to contribute this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARJENV0qGdY 

It shows what happens if you shift into reverse while driving (+/-) 100 km/h, and has a nice illustration of how reverse works in a gearbox after.

Comment: @AlexHumphrey - are you me? I was going to post almost exactly the same comment (2001 Focus; 2013 B-Max and just about all other Fords I've owned). No grinding, no kickback, just not quite engaging properly. My wife finds it hilarious (and assumes it's always my fault) but she doesn't drive, so her opinion is suspect in my view. Vauxhalls and a Peugot I've owned tended to grind rather than not quite make it, but to be fair that was a _long_ time ago. I now look forward to better engagement when I upgrade (probably another B-Max),

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's common for manual transmissions to not have the same gear syncronizing mechanism on reverse gear as it does on forward gears. The job of the synchronizer is not just to match the speeds of cogs that are about to mate, but to align the teeth so that they slide and interleave with each other. While reverse gears would ideally have the same alignment sync property they don't typically need the rotational speed sync mechanism because we (should/could) only shift into reverse when the vehicle is stationary

I suspect that you frequently manage to engage your reverse gears in such a way that the teeth bang into each other rather than interleaving as they should; perhaps you notice that when you "miss" reverse even though the stick looks like it's in the right "slot", it's not "fully back/forwards" compared to where it normally is. Moving to another gear causes a shift in the gear positions in the box and after this reverse is able to engage. Other actions, such as briefly raising the clutch or letting the car roll would also shift the cog positions, allowing the teeth to mate, though arguably the safest route is the one you currently take.

In terms of what's wrong, perhaps the previous owner played "if you can't find it, grind it" often with the reverse gear and has worn the teeth, that used to have meeting angled faces that assisted alignment, so that one or both now have flat spots; occasionally these flat spots collide directly, and cannot perform their function of causing cog rotation/alignment as they slide past each other:

[image]

[Image credit:](https://www.uniquecarsandparts.com.au/how_it_works_synchromesh)

Note that this image above makes most sense in combination with the following image:

[image]

The conical shape of the pink cog synchronizes the speeds, then it is the job of the angled faces on the two mating cogs to align the teeth. A reverse gear doesn't need the conical portion but it still needs angled teeth. Imagine what could happen some percentage of the time if the points of the angled teeth were worn flat so they engaged flat-to-flat rather than slope-to-slope:

[image]

It's an exaggerated image to make the point; teeth shaped with a flat will not engage if the flats meet (left diagram) but will if the slopes meet (right diagam), giving rise to a percentage risk of collide rather than slide. If your gear teeth happen to randomly be in the right place, reverse will engage. If in the wrong place, you have to do something to jiggle the gear positions

Comment: Additionally, the older/more mileage on  the gearbox, the more likely this is.  There's a definite knack to shifting a 40+ year old box compared to something "fresher"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a gear popping out into neutral means a serious damage inside (either bearings or the selection mechanism).

Bearings usually make noise under load (no-load noise of a gearbox is another, almost unrelated matter).

And I have a car that pops the reverse just because the stick bumps into the seat and doesn't fully engage. Moving the seat one step back from where my wife likes it solves the problem.